# How Ix in the give fig. is Zero in 2nd Step?

Tags: circuit-analysis, current, thevenin

[image: thevenins Theorem]
How the ix in the second step is zero

Comment: This looks like home work; please show us what you have tried so far and where you get stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When short-circuiting A and B the voltage across the 6 ohm resistor will be 0 and hence the current Ix will be zero.
This is one of the steps to get the Thevenin equivalent circuit (to get Rth in particular).